# PHP script got a loop

Tags: php, loops

I made a email script to mail a table filed by a php query. It works but i receive everytime more then 20 times the same email. But i can't find a loop at all. Who can help me?

```
<?php

require_once("view_orders.php");

$to  = 'mymail';
$subject = 'Broodje bestelling';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Put your HTML here
$message = file_get_contents('http://myurl.com/order/mail.php', true);

// Mail it
return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: How is it being invoked?

Comment: How are you calling this script?

Comment: Why do you make : return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no loop there.

Based on the way your file is set up, my hunch is that you are calling this file multiple times. Do you have any require/includes that link back to this file? Dig deep. Any time you find a reference, follow it, starting with view_orders.php.

Another note - it would probably be better if you make this a function and then call the function, like this:

require_once("view_orders.php");

```
function send_this_email()
{
    $to  = 'mymail';
    $subject = 'Broodje bestelling';

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Put your HTML here
    $message = file_get_contents('http://myurl.com/order/mail.php', true);

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

It is much easier to debug, and reference, functions this way. From now on, if you do it this way, you simply include this file, and then execute the function `send_this_email();`.

This is a very minor change you can make, but by putting your scripts into functions and calling functions, you'll be far better organized than you are today. It will save you a great amount of time!